# Create / Add lifecylce configuration for individual object

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I want to set different Expiration date for some object in S3 bucket using aws-sdk Node Js. I used `putBucketLifecycleConfiguration` and `putBucketLifecycle` for this purpose. As per my knowledge I used different prefix(= object name) to set expiration day for different object. But this method instead of creating new life-cycle, is replacing existing one.

```
const params = {
 Bucket: Env.AWS_BUCKET, /* required */
 LifecycleConfiguration: {
   Rules: [
    {
      Expiration: {
        Days: 1
    }, 
  Filter: {
     Prefix: fullPathOfObject
   }, 
  Status: "Enabled"
  }
 ]
}
};

const putBucketLifecycleConfigRequest = s3.putBucketLifecycleConfiguration(params);

putBucketLifecycleConfigRequest.
on('success', function(response: any) { 
console.log("success");
}).
on('error', function(error: any) {
console.log(error);
}).
on('complete', function(response: any) {
console.log("complete");
}).
send();

/***
const putBucketLifecycleRequest = s3.putBucketLifecycle(params);

putBucketLifecycleRequest.
 on('success', function(response: any) { 
 console.log("success");
 }).
 on('error', function(error: any) {
 console.log("error");
 }).
 on('complete', function(response: any) {
 console.log("complete");
 }).
 send();

**/
```

I've read many answers and docs but can't figure how to create more than one life cycle in s3 bucket.

In AWS docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#putBucketLifecycle-property

Its written " **Creates a new lifecycle configuration for the bucket or replaces an existing lifecycle configuration**". So, can't we create / add  lifecylce for individual object ?

Comment: Is this all the code you have? Where are you getting `fullPathOfObject` from?

Comment: This one I'm passing from parameters. And full path is the location of objects. And we can give any name to prefix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to await a `callback`, you need to await a `promise`

```
const params = {
    Bucket: 'aws-bucket-name' 
    LifecycleConfiguration: {
        Rules: [
            {
                Expiration: {
                    Days: 1,
                },
                Filter: {
                    Prefix: fullPathOfObject,
                },
                Status: 'Enabled',
            },
        ..add another rule here
        ],
    },
}

await s3.putBucketLifecycleConfiguration(params).promise()
```

As per the documentation below, this will create a new *bucket* lifecycle if there is not already one there and replace an existing. So this is working as expected.

As far as I'm aware you'll need to add *another* rule

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#putBucketLifecycleConfiguration-property

Comment: Expiration date for an object is already set due to my code. I'm waiting for the object to delete at that time. After that i will apply your code.

Comment: No its not working, Its replacing previous one. But I'm able to add new lifecycle using aws website.

Comment: Did you add the extra rule?

Comment: It's a put operation, so you'd need to add both policies at the same time otherwise it will overwrite the previous one...

Comment: Yes Razki, Now its working. I  fetch all the lifecycle rules using getlifecycle configuration first and then append  new rule to that list and then use putbucketlifecycleconfiguration.

Comment: Cool, well if that answer helped, please select it! Cheers

Answer (score 1):

`putBucketLifecycleConfiguration creates a new lifecycle configuration for the bucket or replaces an existing lifecycle configuration.`

So,fetch all the lifecycle rules using `getBucketLifecycleConfiguration` first and then append your new rule to that list and then use `putBucketLifecycleConfiguration`.

Note:  ID should be unique.